# I would like invisible borders in my table... and it's not trivial at all

Tags: html, css, cs-cart

here is the page: lafactory.com/affiliation
I tried cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" and it does not work at all. I am stuck!
I tried to find the css class, no way... so if someone has the answer?

Comment: please post your current HTML and CSS code so we can help

Comment: why would anybody waste their time searching for where are your css files and then try to read line by line of those files to know where exactly the problem is with your borders?? you either put here enough details and also your code so people will understand and help you or you hire someone to fix that for you.

Comment: You are rude. Nobody needs that kind of comments.

Answer (score 0):

[image: DevTools View]
As you can see the td has a border. Remove it from your CSS and you're good to go.